# android app memory question

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can an android app read the memory (the RAM meory) of another app that is running?

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Kudos for the second sentence, if you meant it that way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the part of the memory that another app is using for code? Then No. 
I assume that someone might find a way, but that would be a security issue, a bug in the system and something that would be adressed in an update. You should stay out of 'other' pieces of RAM.

Or do you mean something like internal memory where you can store a file? An app can save a file in several ways, including some that let other apps read them (example: if you take a picture with a cam-app, you can read it with any gallery app).